# Can't assign correct data to model through event emit

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

everyone. I'm working on a project and I'm stuck on a particular point. On the backend side, I'm using Laravel 5.6 and MySQL. I make a request that returns a simple JSON like this:

{
  id: 1,
  name: "someone",
  salary_min: 2600.5,
  salary_max: 3512.35
}

And I fecth this result in the frontend using Vue + axios like any other GET request and assign to a list of employees.

```js
this.axios.get(process.env.ROOT_API + 'employee/${id}', auth)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.data) {
      this.employee = response.data;
    }
  }, (error) => { 
      console.log(error.response.data);
 });
```

I'm passing this data to another child component througn a method defined like so:

```js
onEdit (id) {
  // Send data received from axios and stored in 'emmployee'
  bus.$emit('editEmployee', this.employee);
}
```

Inside the child component, I'm listening to the event like this:

```js
mounted () {
  bus.$on('editEmployee', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.newEmployee = data;
    console.log(this.newEmployee);
  }
}
```

The result of log is as following:

```js
// data from parent component
{ id: 1, name: "someone", salary_min: 2600.5, salary_max: 3512.35 }

// newEmployee model
{ id: 1, name: "someone", salary_min: "0.00", salary_max: "0.00" }
```

Somehow, during assignment, the decimal values are being zeroed and converted to string. I can't understand what's happening. Any clue?

Comment: You are trying to send data from parent to child components? Can you debug `this.employee` inside `onEdit` method pls?

Comment: Jérôme, the console shows the object exactly like this:

{ { id: 1, name: "someone", salary_min: 2600.5, salary_max: 3512.35 }

Comment: But I forgot a detail: This comes from a axios.get request and it is passed through $emit event to another component. From the other component, I get this value and assign it to the model that will be used to fill in the Update Form. By the way, this is the only trouble I have: whenever I try to update a a single employee... It seems like the value gets zeroed before gets assigned to the model.

Comment: `this.newEmployee = data;` should only assign data without changing types to `this.newEmployee`. I tried to reproduce your problem without success, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/478769/

Comment: Thank you very much, Jérôme. I found a way to assign it.